# how to create socket in cpp that should work on windows and linux?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2017, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i tried with the boost.asio is not work properly some time read and write is failed. even i send some size of data to read write function.

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
         tcp::socket socket(io);
         socket.connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 2361));
         boost::system::error_code error;
 write(socket, buffer(s), error);// write
         if (error)
             cout << "error in write " << endl;read(socket, recv,transfer_at_least(130), error);
         if (error)
             cout << "error in read" << endl;
         else
         {
             const char* data = buffer_cast<const char*>(recv.data());
             string s(data);
             return s;
         }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which error does Asio report when reading/writing fails? Please edit your question to include this information. It would also help a lot if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also note that the `visual-studio-2017` flag is intended for questions that are directly related to Visual Studio (your problem seems to be related to the use of Asio).

Answer (score 0):

You can try JUCE.
Is a powerful lib with tons of cross-platform resources.
I use it to make apps for Android and tools that run both in Linux and Windows.
I made some basic tests using `StreamingSocket`, and worked fine.

[JUCE Index](https://docs.juce.com/master/index.html)

[JUCE Core Network](https://docs.juce.com/master/group__juce__core-network.html)